# After adding storybook to create-react-app application, dev server started consuming a lot of memory

Tags: memory-leaks, create-react-app, storybook

I have a project, created with create-react-app

After adding the storybook, the dev server started falling with out-of-memory

I can hot-fix it with `--max-old-space-size`, but that looks like a poor solution.
Maybe someone can point at a potential solution (aside from migrating to `vite`)

UPD - storybook's own dev server is running normally

Storybook version 7.3 (latest)
react scripts v 5.0.1